# Joining elements in list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the data below, I want to find the unique values in 'a' and sum the data for the corresponding indices from 'b', 'c'. Any ideas on the best way to do this? I'm not sure where to start.

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'w']
b = [  1,   4,   5,   7,   9,  5]
c = [  3,   6,   7,   8,   9,  7]
```

After processing,

```
a = ['x', 'y',  'z',  'w']
b = [ 10,   4,   12,   5 ]
c = [ 12,   6,   15,   7 ]
```

Comment: start with `for i,ltr in enumerate(a)`

Comment: Does the order of items in `a` matter?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep the original order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could do something like this using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), since you need to maintain the same order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'w']
b = [  1,   4,   5,   7,   9,  5]
c = [  3,   6,   7,   8,   9,  7]
b_data = OrderedDict()
c_data = OrderedDict()

for letter, b_value, c_value in zip(a, b, c):
    if letter in b_data:
        b_data[letter] += b_value
        c_data[letter] += c_value
    else:
        b_data[letter] = b_value
        c_data[letter] = c_value

a = b_data.keys()
b = b_data.values()
c = c_data.values()


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
[10, 4, 12, 5]
[12, 6, 15, 7]
```

Comment: `for letter, b_value, c_value in zip(a, b, c):` would make this a little shorter.

Comment: `b_data[letter] = b_data.get(letter, 0) + b_value` would also be shorter but perhaps less readable.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: thanks for the suggestions! I've updated to use your first suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'w']
b = [  1,   4,   5,   7,   9,  5]
c = [  3,   6,   7,   8,   9,  7]

b_unique = collections.defaultdict(int)
c_unique = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, bv, cv in zip(a,b,c):
    b_unique[k] += bv
    c_unique[k] += cv
```

Comment: `defaultdict` was my first thought, but the OP states that the order of the keys matters.

Answer (score 2):

Using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# To keep original order of values.
a_ordered = [val for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val not in a[:idx]]
# >>> a_ordered
# OUT: ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}).groupby('a').sum().T[a_ordered]
a = df.columns.tolist()
b, c = df.values.tolist()

>>> a
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

>>> b
[10, 4, 12, 5]

>>> c
[12, 6, 15, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just felt like playing a little code-golf:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> for t in zip(a,zip(b,c)):
...   od[t[0]] = [i + x for i,x in zip(od.get(t[0],[0,0]), t[1])]
... 
>>> od
OrderedDict([('x', [10, 12]), ('y', [4, 6]), ('z', [12, 15]), ('w', [5, 7])])
>>> a = list(od.keys())
>>> b,c = map(list,zip(*od.values()))
>>> a
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
>>> b
[10, 4, 12, 5]
>>> c
[12, 6, 15, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: `for k,bv,cv in zip(a,b,c):v1,v2=od.get(k,(0,0));od[k]=(bv+v1,cv+v2)`

Answer (score 0):

here is an elementary approach

```
d1 = defaultdict(int)
d2 = defaultdict(int)
for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
    d1[x] += y
    d2[x] += z

an=list()
bn=list()
cn=list()

for k in sorted(d1.keys(), key=lambda x:a.index(x)):
    an.append(k)
    bn.append(d1[k])
    cn.append(d2[k])

[an,bn,cn]


[['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'], [10, 4, 12, 5], [12, 6, 15, 7]]
```